# Is there a way to convert raw MPU-6050 data to a 0-359 rotational data

Tags: c++, unity-game-engine, arduino

Im building a Oculus Quest this week. Its meant to be a fun (cheap) project to work on And I figured out how to calculate limb displacement if a constant(foot placement) position is tracked positonaly. I have already to manage to add more than 2 MPU-6050s on the same arduino at once. The problem comes when I want to take the serial data from the MPU and put it into unity. The rotational data is very wrong it looks like this:

```
gyro    -8.00   -171.00 -148.00  |||    gyro    117.00  -639.00 -1105.00    
gyro    -4.00   -160.00 -125.00  |||    gyro    -20.00  -640.00 -1081.00    
gyro    -9.00   -160.00 -128.00  |||    gyro    -86.00  -694.00 -1074.00    
gyro    13.00   -141.00 -120.00  |||    gyro    -309.00 -713.00 -1040.00    
gyro    -8.00   -136.00 -134.00  |||    gyro    -184.00 -683.00 -1045.00    
gyro    -6.00   -150.00 -158.00  |||    gyro    -214.00 -696.00 -1058.00    
gyro    -12.00  -143.00 -147.00  |||    gyro    -5.00   -644.00 -1086.00    
gyro    16.00   -157.00 -140.00  |||    gyro    42.00   -662.00 -1153.00    
gyro    -9.00   -151.00 -136.00  |||    gyro    54.00   -644.00 -1154.00    
gyro    8.00    -143.00 -143.00  |||    gyro    81.00   -662.00 -1149.00    
gyro    -17.00  -124.00 -134.00  |||    gyro    -126.00 -698.00 -1088.00    
gyro    -11.00  -150.00 -138.00  |||    gyro    -28.00  -703.00 -1169.00    
gyro    -1.00   -129.00 -161.00  |||    gyro    -187.00 -744.00 -1125.00    
gyro    -23.00  -145.00 -133.00  |||    gyro    -43.00  -713.00 -1117.00    
gyro    1.00    -143.00 -139.00  |||    gyro    -7.00   -662.00 -1160.00    
gyro    11.00   -156.00 -136.00  |||    gyro    20.00   -697.00 -1178.00    
gyro    21.00   -132.00 -116.00  |||    gyro    168.00  -651.00 -1162.00    
gyro    -1.00   -133.00 -153.00  |||    gyro    -41.00  -688.00 -1151.00    
gyro    -5.00   -174.00 -144.00  |||    gyro    107.00  -699.00 -1157.00    
gyro    2.00    -144.00 -146.00  |||    gyro    -177.00 -710.00 -1105.00    
gyro    -31.00  -134.00 -133.00  |||    gyro    -124.00 -687.00 -1091.00    
gyro    -8.00   -169.00 -121.00  |||    gyro    -114.00 -695.00 -1133.00    
gyro    -11.00  -178.00 -151.00  |||    gyro    -132.00 -662.00 -1074.00    
gyro    -20.00  -154.00 -132.00  |||    gyro    62.00   -659.00 -1136.00    
gyro    22.00   -142.00 -135.00  |||    gyro    -88.00  -665.00 -1116.00    
gyro    -30.00  -148.00 -131.00  |||    gyro    51.00   -683.00 -1144.00    
gyro    -2.00   -163.00 -129.00  |||    gyro    -111.00 -699.00 -1119.00    
gyro    -9.00   -164.00 -128.00  |||    gyro    -58.00  -706.00 -1114.00    
gyro    4.00    -146.00 -146.00  |||    gyro    -52.00  -699.00 -1121.00    
gyro    12.00   -149.00 -138.00  |||    gyro    -147.00 -707.00 -1092.00    
gyro    -24.00  -146.00 -131.00  |||    gyro    -2.00   -701.00 -1164.00    
gyro    -7.00   -135.00 -142.00  |||    gyro    -38.00  -700.00 -1137.00    
gyro    -2.00   -169.00 -139.00  |||    gyro    92.00   -636.00 -1156.00    
gyro    -12.00  -160.00 -145.00  |||    gyro    -52.00  -658.00 -1094.00    
gyro    -12.00  -145.00 -131.00  |||    gyro    -27.00  -689.00 -1137.00    
gyro    -22.00  -139.00 -134.00  |||    gyro    -42.00  -723.00 -1122.00    
gyro    0.00    -149.00 -133.00  |||    gyro    -54.00  -682.00 -1096.00    
gyro    -15.00  -173.00 -124.00  |||    gyro    24.00   -688.00 -1127.00    
gyro    9.00    -163.00 -139.00  |||    gyro    -117.00 -682.00 -1080.00    
gyro    -21.00  -151.00 -128.00  |||    gyro    21.00   -662.00 -1137.00    
gyro    20.00   -101.00 -159.00  |||    gyro    -96.00  -636.00 -1051.00    
gyro    -5.00   -166.00 -132.00  |||    gyro    -135.00 -693.00 -1128.00    
gyro    -10.00  -149.00 -123.00  |||    gyro    -173.00 -699.00 -1112.00    
gyro    14.00   -165.00 -135.00  |||    gyro    -91.00  -723.00 -1134.00    
gyro    -12.00  -163.00 -151.00  |||    gyro    255.00  -670.00 -1163.00    
gyro    -10.00  -158.00 -144.00  |||    gyro    95.00   -612.00 -1163.00    
gyro    0.00    -150.00 -130.00  |||    gyro    17.00   -693.00 -1195.00    
gyro    -18.00  -159.00 -146.00  |||    gyro    -59.00  -728.00 -1161.00    
gyro    2.00    -183.00 -114.00  |||    gyro    -40.00  -740.00 -1148.00    
gyro    3.00    -164.00 -107.00  |||    gyro    80.00   -729.00 -1201.00    
gyro    -17.00  -148.00 -128.00  |||    gyro    -141.00 -682.00 -1147.00    
gyro    14.00   -158.00 -147.00  |||    gyro    112.00  -696.00 -1145.00    
gyro    -1.00   -139.00 -136.00  |||    gyro    -116.00 -731.00 -1091.00    
gyro    -11.00  -136.00 -128.00  |||    gyro    -64.00  -735.00 -1111.00    
gyro    -2.00   -150.00 -133.00  |||    gyro    -151.00 -757.00 -1092.00    
gyro    -21.00  -136.00 -129.00  |||    gyro    -156.00 -714.00 -1139.00    
gyro    -20.00  -163.00 -111.00  |||    gyro    42.00   -738.00 -1116.00    
gyro    -16.00  -160.00 -141.00  |||    gyro    -141.00 -681.00 -1108.00    
gyro    -8.00   -176.00 -129.00  |||    gyro    80.00   -691.00 -1142.00    
gyro    -6.00   -167.00 -159.00  |||    gyro    -52.00  -725.00 -1119.00    
gyro    -10.00  -178.00 -135.00  |||    gyro    -62.00  -706.00 -1069.00    
gyro    -16.00  -173.00 -136.00  |||    gyro    -129.00 -735.00 -1112.00    
gyro    9.00    -147.00 -158.00  |||    gyro    -203.00 -734.00 -1132.00    
gyro    12.00   -152.00 -131.00  |||    gyro    -12.00  -720.00 -1158.00    
gyro    -24.00  -163.00 -146.00  |||    gyro    -76.00  -737.00 -1141.00    
gyro    27.00   -153.00 -128.00  |||    gyro    190.00  -676.00 -1162.00    
gyro    1.00    -150.00 -129.00  |||    gyro    23.00   -669.00 -1123.00    
gyro    -14.00  -146.00 -131.00  |||    gyro    51.00   -672.00 -1180.00    
gyro    0.00    -134.00 -115.00  |||    gyro    -4.00   -706.00 -1171.00    
gyro    -6.00   -145.00 -139.00  |||    gyro    -160.00 -730.00 -1147.00    
gyro    -16.00  -165.00 -152.00  |||    gyro    -82.00  -705.00 -1112.00    
gyro    14.00   -152.00 -147.00  |||    gyro    -246.00 -696.00 -1089.00    
gyro    -14.00  -162.00 -137.00  |||    gyro    33.00   -705.00 -1162.00    
gyro    -22.00  -174.00 -152.00  |||    gyro    -31.00  -664.00 -1161.00    
gyro    -1.00   -138.00 -131.00  |||    gyro    137.00  -642.00 -1141.00    
gyro    4.00    -173.00 -134.00  |||    gyro    165.00  -652.00 -1168.00    
gyro    9.00    -152.00 -133.00  |||    gyro    -23.00  -666.00 -1111.00    
gyro    -12.00  -146.00 -134.00  |||    gyro    64.00   -697.00 -1128.00    
gyro    -20.00  -132.00 -141.00  |||    gyro    -221.00 -695.00 -1046.00    
gyro    -7.00   -143.00 -141.00  |||    gyro    -122.00 -684.00 -1116.00    
gyro    -7.00   -118.00 -150.00  |||    gyro    -188.00 -699.00 -1097.00    
gyro    -9.00   -148.00 -126.00  |||    gyro    -56.00  -686.00 -1107.00    
gyro    6.00    -169.00 -130.00  |||    gyro    132.00  -665.00 -1152.00    
gyro    -1.00   -150.00 -119.00  |||    gyro    22.00   -615.00 -1144.00    
gyro    12.00   -157.00 -120.00  |||    gyro    212.00  -678.00 -1163.00    
gyro    5.00    -156.00 -153.00  |||    gyro    -42.00  -745.00 -1169.00    
gyro    -2.00   -143.00 -130.00  |||    gyro    22.00   -732.00 -1171.00    
gyro    3.00    -129.00 -142.00  |||    gyro    -145.00 -730.00 -1123.00    
gyro    -2.00   -132.00 -154.00  |||    gyro    -147.00 -705.00 -1140.00    
gyro    -9.00   -120.00 -132.00  |||    gyro    -85.00  -691.00 -1143.00    
gyro    -12.00  -156.00 -153.00  |||    gyro    -157.00 -696.00 -1087.00    
gyro    -11.00  -149.00 -141.00  |||    gyro    67.00   -681.00 -1095.00    
gyro    -21.00  -167.00 -140.00  |||    gyro    -72.00  -673.00 -1100.00    
gyro    19.00   -156.00 -138.00  |||    gyro    76.00   -687.00 -1139.00    
gyro    -17.00  -135.00 -144.00  |||    gyro    -55.00  -693.00 -1107.00    
gyro    -6.00   -136.00 -129.00  |||    gyro    -72.00  -721.00 -1091.00    
gyro    26.00   -146.00 -146.00  |||    gyro    -42.00  -681.00 -1084.00    
gyro    5.00    -133.00 -125.00  |||    gyro    -135.00 -694.00 -1101.00    
gyro    -1.00   -152.00 -124.00  |||    gyro    5.00    -674.00 -1173.00    
gyro    1.00    -144.00 -116.00  |||    gyro    -81.00  -676.00 -1110.00    
gyro    -8.00   -140.00 -127.00  |||    gyro    32.00   -671.00 -1144.00    
gyro    17.00   -144.00 -144.00  |||    gyro    60.00   -682.00 -1163.00    
gyro    8.00    -169.00 -122.00  |||    gyro    16.00   -671.00 -1151.00    
gyro    16.00   -163.00 -128.00  |||    gyro    134.00  -703.00 -1200.00    
gyro    -16.00  -178.00 -133.00  |||    gyro    -62.00  -671.00 -1127.00    
gyro    -2.00   -157.00 -141.00  |||    gyro    128.00  -738.00 -1190.00    
gyro    -32.00  -147.00 -134.00  |||    gyro    -189.00 -664.00 -1139.00
```

To my eyes it seems as if the 2 MPU-6050s are having their data calulated diferently,(they are supposed to not have any functions applied to them right now). In the end I want it to be rotational data mapped to 0-359. I know Jeff Rowberg has a great library for this but I want to do this myself so I understand it for the future so I can modify it. My code:

```
#include <Wire.h>

long accelX, accelY, accelZ;
float gForceX, gForceY, gForceZ, gyroX, gyroY, gyroZ,rotX, rotY, rotZ;
long accelX2, accelY2, accelZ2;
float gForceX2, gForceY2, gForceZ2;

void setup(){
  //write all ADO's to high to raise thieR adress to 0x69
  pinMode(22, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(22, HIGH);
  pinMode(23, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(23, HIGH);
  pinMode(24, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(24, HIGH);

  Wire.begin();
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x69);
  Wire.write(0x6B);
  Wire.write(0b00000000);
  Wire.endTransmission();  
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x69);
  Wire.write(0x1B);
  Wire.write(0x00000000);
  Wire.endTransmission(); 
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x69);
  Wire.write(0x1C);
  Wire.write(0b00000000);
  Wire.endTransmission(); 

  Wire.begin();
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x68);
  Wire.write(0x6B);
  Wire.write(0b00000000);
  Wire.endTransmission();  
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x68);
  Wire.write(0x1B);
  Wire.write(0x00000000);
  Wire.endTransmission(); 
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x68);
  Wire.write(0x1C);
  Wire.write(0b00000000);
  Wire.endTransmission(); 

  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop(){
  GetMpuValue(22);
  Serial.print("\t ||| \t");
  GetMpuValue(23);
  Serial.println("\t");
}

void GetMpuValue(int pin){
  digitalWrite(pin, LOW);
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x68); 
  Wire.write(0x3B);
  Wire.endTransmission();
  Wire.requestFrom(0x68,6);

  Wire.beginTransmission(0x68);
  Wire.write(0x43);
  Wire.endTransmission();
  Wire.requestFrom(0x68,6);
  while(Wire.available() < 6);
  gyroX = Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();
  gyroY = Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();
  gyroZ = Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read(); 
  digitalWrite(pin, HIGH);

  Serial.print("gyro\t");
  Serial.print(gyroX);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(gyroY);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(gyroZ);
}
```

Ty you guys in advance!

Comment: Are you sure it is returning a 16-bit float value? Try reading 16-bit ints.

Comment: Sorry a bit new to arduino. Could you explain more beacause I do not know what that means.

Comment: You have declare `gyroX, gyroZ, gyroX` as `float`. I'm suggesting trying to declare them as `int`.

Comment: This changes the data type, what does it have to do with getting crazy numbers like `-1178.00`

Comment: -1178 / 131 = -9°/sec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration of gyro is given by these lines:

```
Wire.beginTransmission(0x68); // Start communication with MPU-1
Wire.write(0x1B);             // Request the GYRO_CONFIG register
Wire.write(0x00);             // Apply the desired configuration to the register : + or -250°/s
Wire.endTransmission();       // End the transmission


Wire.beginTransmission(0x69); // Start communication with MPU-2
Wire.write(0x1B);             // Request the GYRO_CONFIG register
Wire.write(0x00);             // Apply the desired configuration to the register : + or -250°/s
Wire.endTransmission();       // End the transmission
```

so they have to have the same configuration...

fyi the configuration of gyro is given by:

[image]

So in your program i see the calculus of MPU with adress 0X68 but not with the adress 0x69?  a multiplexer junction??

Another thing i dont see the configuration of filter for both mpu:(i dont know if all mpu have this functionality read the datasheet of your mpu see in my comment))

[image]

```
Wire.beginTransmission(0x68); // Start communication with MPU
Wire.write(0x1A);             // Request the CONFIG register
Wire.write(0x03);             // Apply the desired config to the register : DLPF about 43Hz
Wire.endTransmission();       // End the transmission
```

After if you want to read angular measure from raw data, you just divide by 131 as show the diagram of mpu:  (you have selected FS_SEL to 0 (-+250deg/sec)   so your value is rawvalue / 131 = deg/seconde

you see 250 x 131 = 32750  (int max value = 32767)

[image]

Just one thing, a gyroscope accumulatedrift see [here](https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/raqs/raq-issue-139.html#),

so my complete code i am using with my settings

---

My complete sample

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                              
#include <Wire.h>                                                                                                                                 
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                          
#define YAW   0                                                                                                                                   
#define PITCH 1                                                                                                                                   
#define ROLL  2                                                                                                                                   

#define X     0     // X axis                                                                                                                     
#define Y     1     // Y axis                                                                                                                     
#define Z     2     // Z axis                                                                                                                     

#define MPU_ADDRESS 0x68  // I2C address of the MPU-6050                                                                                          
#define FREQ        250   // Sampling frequency                                                                                                   
#define SSF_GYRO    65.5  // Sensitivity Scale Factor of the gyro from datasheet                                                                  
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                          
// The RAW values got from gyro (in °/sec) in that order: X, Y, Z                                                                                 
int gyro_raw[3] = {0, 0, 0};                                                                                                                      

// Average gyro offsets of each axis in that order: X, Y, Z                                                                                       
long gyro_offset[3] = {0, 0, 0};                                                                                                                  

// Calculated angles from gyro's values in that order: X, Y, Z                                                                                    
float gyro_angle[3]  = {0, 0, 0};                                                                                                                 

// The RAW values got from accelerometer (in m/sec²) in that order: X, Y, Z                                                                       
int acc_raw[3] = {0 , 0 , 0};                                                                                                                     

// Calculated angles from accelerometer's values in that order: X, Y, Z                                                                           
float acc_angle[3] = {0, 0, 0};                                                                                                                   

// Total 3D acceleration vector in m/s²                                                                                                           
long acc_total_vector;                                                                                                                            

/**                                                                                                                                               
 * Real measures on 3 axis calculated from gyro AND accelerometer in that order : Yaw, Pitch, Roll                                                
 *  - Left wing up implies a positive roll                                                                                                        
 *  - Nose up implies a positive pitch                                                                                                            
 *  - Nose right implies a positive yaw                                                                                                           
 */                                                                                                                                               
float measures[3] = {0, 0, 0};                                                                                                                    

// MPU's temperature                                                                                                                              
int temperature;                                                                                                                                  

// Init flag set to TRUE after first loop                                                                                                         
boolean initialized;                                                                                                                              

unsigned int  period; // Sampling period                                                                                                          
unsigned long loop_timer;                                                                                                                         
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                          
void setup() {                                                                                                                                    
//  Serial.begin(57600); Only for debug                                                                                                           
  Wire.begin();                                                                                                                                   
  TWBR = 24; // 400kHz I2C clock (200kHz if CPU is 8MHz)                                                                                          

  setupMpu6050Registers();                                                                                                                        
  calibrateMpu6050();                                                                                                                             

  loop_timer = micros();                                                                                                                          
  period = (1000000 / FREQ) ; // Sampling period in µs                                                                                            
}
```

---

```
void loop() {                                                                                                                                     
  readSensor();                                                                                                                                   
  calculateAngles();                                                                                                                              

  while (micros() - loop_timer < period);                                                                                                         
  loop_timer = micros();                                                                                                                          
}
```

Comment: The reason why im setting all the AD0's to high is to raise them all to 0x69 and can manually lower one MPU to 0x68 so I can add more than 2 MPUs and only talk to one at a time. I also added the 0x1A, 0x03 @Frenchy recommended and all of my data looks like this:`gyro -255 -255 -255  |||  gyro -255 -255 -256 ` and a lot of the data (specificly x on the first gyro) has started giving alot of `0`'s

Comment: ok i understant your wiring....so about your filter,  maybe you dont have it..because there are lot of variant of mpu...and some coming from china are really basics...(so the filter is using to reduce parasites in transmition and if dont exist all values could be ignored)...in anyway in your case rawValue/131 gives the velocity  in degrees/sec  the datasheet is here:https://invensense.tdk.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/MPU-6000-Register-Map1.pdf

Comment: so i five you my fucntional sample. I have put a mpu on Drone and just divide the rawvalues is not enought (for my project) i nhave needed to calibrate and eliminate the dirft. i dont know if you have needed of this precision..

Comment: is it functional?

Answer (score 1):

the end of code:

```
/**                                                                                                                                               
 * Configure gyro and accelerometer precision as following:                                                                                       
 *  - accelerometer: ±8g                                                                                                                          
 *  - gyro: ±500°/s                                                                                                                               
 *                                                                                                                                                
 * @see https://www.invensense.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/MPU-6000-Register-Map1.pdf                                                          
 * @return void                                                                                                                                   
 */                                                                                                                                               
void setupMpu6050Registers() {                                                                                                                    
  // Configure power management                                                                                                                   
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU_ADDRESS); // Start communication with MPU                                                                            
  Wire.write(0x6B);                    // Request the PWR_MGMT_1 register                                                                         
  Wire.write(0x00);                    // Apply the desired configuration to the register                                                         
  Wire.endTransmission();              // End the transmission                                                                                    

  // Configure the gyro's sensitivity                                                                                                             
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU_ADDRESS); // Start communication with MPU                                                                            
  Wire.write(0x1B);                    // Request the GYRO_CONFIG register                                                                        
  Wire.write(0x08);                    // Apply the desired configuration to the register : ±500°/s                                               
  Wire.endTransmission();              // End the transmission                                                                                    

  // Configure the acceleromter's sensitivity                                                                                                     
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU_ADDRESS); // Start communication with MPU                                                                            
  Wire.write(0x1C);                    // Request the ACCEL_CONFIG register                                                                       
  Wire.write(0x10);                    // Apply the desired configuration to the register : ±8g                                                   
  Wire.endTransmission();              // End the transmission                                                                                    

  // Configure low pass filter if exists                                                                                                                                                
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU_ADDRESS); // Start communication with MPU                                                                            
  Wire.write(0x1A);                    // Request the CONFIG register                                                                             
  Wire.write(0x03);                    // Set Digital Low Pass Filter about ~43Hz                                                                 
  Wire.endTransmission();              // End the transmission                                                                                    
}
```

---

```
/**                                                                                                                                               
 * Calibrate MPU6050: take 2000 samples to calculate average offsets.                                                                             
 * During this step, the quadcopter needs to be static and on a horizontal surface.                                                               
 *                                                                                                                                                
 * This function also sends low throttle signal to each ESC to init and prevent them beeping annoyingly.                                          
 *                                                                                                                                                
 * This function might take ~2sec for 2000 samples.                                                                                               
 *                                                                                                                                                
 * @return void                                                                                                                                   
 */                                                                                                                                               
void calibrateMpu6050()                                                                                                                           
{                                                                                                                                                 
  int max_samples = 2000;                                                                                                                         

  for (int i = 0; i < max_samples; i++) {                                                                                                         
    readSensor();                                                                                                                                 

    gyro_offset[X] += gyro_raw[X];                                                                                                                
    gyro_offset[Y] += gyro_raw[Y];                                                                                                                
    gyro_offset[Z] += gyro_raw[Z];                                                                                                                

    // Just wait a bit before next loop                                                                                                           
    delay(3);                                                                                                                                     
  }                                                                                                                                               

  // Calculate average offsets                                                                                                                    
  gyro_offset[X] /= max_samples;                                                                                                                  
  gyro_offset[Y] /= max_samples;                                                                                                                  
  gyro_offset[Z] /= max_samples;                                                                                                                  
}
```

---

```
/**                                                                                                                                               
 * Request raw values from MPU6050.                                                                                                               
 *                                                                                                                                                
 * @return void                                                                                                                                   
 */                                                                                                                                               
void readSensor() {                                                                                                                               
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU_ADDRESS); // Start communicating with the MPU-6050                                                                   
  Wire.write(0x3B);                    // Send the requested starting register                                                                    
  Wire.endTransmission();              // End the transmission                                                                                    
  Wire.requestFrom(MPU_ADDRESS, 14);   // Request 14 bytes from the MPU-6050                                                                      

  // Wait until all the bytes are received                                                                                                        
  while (Wire.available() < 14);                                                                                                                  

  acc_raw[X]  = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read(); // Add the low and high byte to the acc_raw[X] variable                                           
  acc_raw[Y]  = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read(); // Add the low and high byte to the acc_raw[Y] variable                                           
  acc_raw[Z]  = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read(); // Add the low and high byte to the acc_raw[Z] variable                                           
  temperature = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read(); // Add the low and high byte to the temperature variable                                          
  gyro_raw[X] = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read(); // Add the low and high byte to the gyro_raw[X] variable                                          
  gyro_raw[Y] = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read(); // Add the low and high byte to the gyro_raw[Y] variable                                          
  gyro_raw[Z] = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read(); // Add the low and high byte to the gyro_raw[Z] variable                                          
}
```

---

```
/**                                                                                                                                               
 * Calculate real angles from gyro and accelerometer's values                                                                                     
 */                                                                                                                                               
void calculateAngles()                                                                                                                            
{                                                                                                                                                 
  calculateGyroAngles();                                                                                                                          
  calculateAccelerometerAngles();                                                                                                                 

  if (initialized) {                                                                                                                              
    // Correct the drift of the gyro with the accelerometer                                                                                       
    gyro_angle[X] = gyro_angle[X] * 0.9996 + acc_angle[X] * 0.0004;                                                                               
    gyro_angle[Y] = gyro_angle[Y] * 0.9996 + acc_angle[Y] * 0.0004;                                                                               
  } else {                                                                                                                                        
    // At very first start, init gyro angles with accelerometer angles                                                                            
    gyro_angle[X] = acc_angle[X];                                                                                                                 
    gyro_angle[Y] = acc_angle[Y];                                                                                                                 

    initialized = true;                                                                                                                           
  }                                                                                                                                               

  // To dampen the pitch and roll angles a complementary filter is used                                                                           
  measures[ROLL]  = measures[ROLL]  * 0.9 + gyro_angle[X] * 0.1;                                                                                  
  measures[PITCH] = measures[PITCH] * 0.9 + gyro_angle[Y] * 0.1;                                                                                  
  measures[YAW]   = -gyro_raw[Z] / SSF_GYRO; // Store the angular motion for this axis                                                            
}
```

---

```
/**                                                                                                                                               
 * Calculate pitch & roll angles using only the gyro.                                                                                             
 */                                                                                                                                               
void calculateGyroAngles()                                                                                                                        
{                                                                                                                                                 
  // Subtract offsets                                                                                                                             
  gyro_raw[X] -= gyro_offset[X];                                                                                                                  
  gyro_raw[Y] -= gyro_offset[Y];                                                                                                                  
  gyro_raw[Z] -= gyro_offset[Z];                                                                                                                  

  // Angle calculation using integration                                                                                                          
  gyro_angle[X] += (gyro_raw[X] / (FREQ * SSF_GYRO));                                                                                             
  gyro_angle[Y] += (-gyro_raw[Y] / (FREQ * SSF_GYRO)); // Change sign to match the accelerometer's one                                            

  // Transfer roll to pitch if IMU has yawed                                                                                                      
  gyro_angle[Y] += gyro_angle[X] * sin(gyro_raw[Z] * (PI / (FREQ * SSF_GYRO * 180)));                                                             
  gyro_angle[X] -= gyro_angle[Y] * sin(gyro_raw[Z] * (PI / (FREQ * SSF_GYRO * 180)));                                                             
}
```

---

```
/**                                                                                                                                               
 * Calculate pitch & roll angles using only the accelerometer.                                                                                    
 */                                                                                                                                               
void calculateAccelerometerAngles()                                                                                                               
{                                                                                                                                                 
  // Calculate total 3D acceleration vector : √(X² + Y² + Z²)                                                                                     
  acc_total_vector = sqrt(pow(acc_raw[X], 2) + pow(acc_raw[Y], 2) + pow(acc_raw[Z], 2));                                                          

  // To prevent asin to produce a NaN, make sure the input value is within [-1;+1]                                                                
  if (abs(acc_raw[X]) < acc_total_vector) {                                                                                                       
    acc_angle[X] = asin((float)acc_raw[Y] / acc_total_vector) * (180 / PI); // asin gives angle in radian. Convert to degree multiplying by 180/pi
  }                                                                                                                                               

  if (abs(acc_raw[Y]) < acc_total_vector) {                                                                                                       
    acc_angle[Y] = asin((float)acc_raw[X] / acc_total_vector) * (180 / PI);                                                                       
  }                                                                                                                                               
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213821/discussion-on-answer-by-frenchy-is-there-a-way-to-convert-raw-mpu-6050-data-to-a).